# Drop frames from video sequence using ffmpeg

Tags: matlab, video, ffmpeg, frame-rate

I have a video sequence, lets say seq.mp4. This sequence consists of frames f_1,f_2,...,f_n and I want to reencode the sequence using ffmpeg such that the new sequence consists only of a subset of frames, in particular, the new sequence shall consist only of the frames f_(u*k), where u=1,...,m and m maximal such that k*m <= n. Here, k >=1 is a natural number.

How can I do that using ffmpeg ?

So in Matlab I would do the following:

```
[str_file,str_path] =  uigetfile('*','choose video file');
filename_video_in=fullfile(strcat(str_path,str_file));
sFrames=  newid('Sub Frames','Subsequence of Frames',1);
k=str2num(sFrames{1});
tmpFolder=tempname;
mkdir(tmpFolder);
video_in=VideoReader(filename_video_in);
for frame_idx=1:video_in.NumberOfFrames
   if mod(frame_idx,k) == 0
    img=read(video_in,frame_idx); 
    fileNumber=frame_idx / k;
    imwrite(img,fullfile(tmpFolder,sprintf('img%d.jpg',fileNumber))); 
   end
end

filename_video_out=strcat(filename_video_in(1:end-4),'_',num2str(k),'-    th_frame.',filename_video_in(end-3:end));
video_out=VideoWriter(filename_video_out);
open(video_out);

images=dir(fullfile(tmpFolder,'*.jpg'));
images={images.name}';
images=sort_nat(images,'ascend');


for frame_idx = 1:length(images)
     img=imread(fullfile(tmpFolder,images{frame_idx}));
     writeVideo(video_out,img);
end


close(video_out);
rmdir(tmpFolder,'s');
```

Comment: Depending on codec, this may be impossible

Comment: Really impossible ? I mean I just want a video sequence, any codec would be ok for me. And one solution, not taking ffmpeg is to load the sequence into matlab, and make a new video out of every k-th frame.

Comment: You can always ask ffmpeg to resample the video with different frame rate. If you have the original at 30 FPS, and the result at 15 FPS, then in some sense you "drop" every second frame. But actually, ffmpeg re-encodes the video; it uses the information from all 30 frames per second to produce the new video. Some codecs, e.g. mjpeg, don't carry intra-frame information, therefore this recoding will simply drop the unused frames. But for h264, for example, the frames depend on others.

Comment: I added the sample code in Matlab. So I was wondering if that is possible in ffmpeg too

Comment: So, you really decode the video, and encode it back with new frame rate. This is easy with `ffmpeg -r 30 -i video -an -r 15 output`